# Publish only transformed config files from a C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-devops, webdeploy

We have a C# ASP.NET MVC solution made of many individual projects that supports multiple solution configurations. Each configuration is in place since each environment requires has different settings, while sharing the same code base.

The settings are stored in multiple `.config` files and environment specific settings are applied using transform files.

For instance, we have a *Logging.config* file located in the *Logging* project which, stores the Logger settings and the related transform files. In Solution Explorer, it looks something like this:

- Logging.config
- Logging.Dev.config
- Logging.UAT.config
- Logging.Prod.config
- etc...

We're creating a build package with Azure DevOps Pipelines however we are forced to rebuild the project multiple times even though the code base isn't affected, therefore we're looking for a way to optimize the process, which ideally should look something like this:

- Build code in Release mode
- Publish configs transformed with Dev settings
- Publish configs transformed with UAT settings
- Publish configs transformed with Prod settings
- etc....

The advantage is that we can deploy the same code in every environment and apply the relevant configs on top of the website directory.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You'd do this at deployment time.  Have 1 build process and then when you deploy to an environment you simply delete the config files for other environments and rename the one for the environment you're deploying to.  It depends how you deploy as to how you do this, but we do the same thing and just have a powershell script that takes a parameter to identify the environment.

Answer (score 0):

After building your project just add a task in the release pipeline called **Azure App Service Deploy** where your transforms will be done automatically if you select **XML transformation** under **File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options** menu:

[image: XML transformation]

Please note that the config transforms will be run for `*.EnvironmentName.config` on the `*.config` file, so all configs have to be equal to environment name. For example if your environment is called test, then your configs should be `*.test.config`
Another approach would be to use **XDT Transform** task, which is intended for this usage. In the transformations field you can set up your transformations like this: `Web.$(environment).config => web.config`, where $(environment) is your variable, where you set your environment name:

[image: XDT transform]

Answer (score 0):

If you use Azure DevOps you have a built-in feature to do the transformation.

In your Release Pipeline whether you deploy to your local IIS (with `IIS Web App Deploy` task) or you deploy to Azure (with `Azure App Service Deploy` task) you have "File Transform & Variable Substitution Option", there you can check the "XML transformation".

[image]

What is the meaning of this option? if you have a config file with the environment name, for example: `*.UAT.config` (and in the release to the envrtiomnent called UAT) so Azure DevOps take the file and will transform with the regular config file.

So, you have **one** build and in the release pipeline you transform the configs file and deploy the app to your environments.

Comment: But this still results in all the environment-specific *.config* files being published whereas the OP wants _only_ the transformed config file published. The task doesn't delete the transformation *.config* files.